# Are processes/headless flows run per record or in bulk?

Tags: flow, process-builder

I just recently got access to the headless flow beta. I've dug through the documentation and searched the Internet but I can't find the answer to my question. When a process kicks off a flow, does it pass records one at a time (like a workflow) or does it pass a list of sobjects (like a trigger would get)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer for this is in below link from Salesforce Docs

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_flow_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US

> When flows are launched from workflow rules that are triggered by bulk loads or imports, the flows’ data manipulation language (DML) operations are executed in bulk to reduce the number of calls required and to optimize system performance. The execution of any of the following flow elements qualifies as a DML operation: Record Create, Record Update, Record Delete, Fast Create, Fast Update, or Fast Delete.
>   For example, suppose that you use Data Loader or the Bulk API to update 50 records, and those updates meet the criteria of a workflow rule with a flow trigger action.

In response, the system executes 50 instances of the flow within the same transaction. Each instance of a running flow is called an interview. The system attempts to execute each DML operation across all the interviews in the transaction at the same time.

Suppose that five of those interviews are executing the same branch of the flow, which has a Record Update element called “SetEntitlement.” The system waits for all five interviews to reach that element, and then executes all five record updates in bulk.

Comment: Thanks Mohith, I must have missed that bit in the documentation. I appreciate your help!