# Do record triggered flows run on multiple records?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, bulkification

I'm trying to implement some logic that I would normally use Apex for, but decided to try record triggered flow so that it would be easier for an admin to turn on or off.

When I create a record triggered flow, there is a variable called 'Record > OBJECT NAME' that I can access from any node. My question is what happens when a number of records are updated/inserted together? Does the flow run on the collection of records?

In apex I would write a trigger helper method that would accept a List, and would iterate over those. Is there something similar in Flow?

If not, that's a serious limitation. If, for instance I create new records for each record that was updated, I will very quickly run into limits if it's a Flow per record.

Comment: Even I have the same doubt, I have a Record Trigger Flow on Contact and if 15 contacts are getting updated, this Record Triggered Flow is getting called 15 times. I don't know how to proceed other than writing an Apex Trigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be an issue.  See the [Flow Bulkification in Transactions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5) article:

> If you’re working with flows, you don’t even have to think about bulkification. Flow interviews bulkify actions for you automatically.

Sounds magical but you'll have to read the whole help doc to see the details.

#### Additional Reads

Similar question and answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/59951/55891) from the early versions of Flow.

Lastly, [look here](https://www.sfdcstop.com/2020/03/are-scheduled-flows-bulkified-lets-find.html) to see a proper test with hundreds of records, and concluded that the bulk is done in 200 record batches:

> Therefore, we conclude that Scheduled Flows are Bulkified and process records in a batch of 200 records.

Comment: Even I have the same doubt, I have a Record Trigger Flow on Contact and if 15 contacts are getting updated, this Record Triggered Flow is getting called 15 times. I don't know how to proceed other than writing an Apex Trigger